# Como usar $.each para recorrer una lista de objeto devuelta por C#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

Uso AJAX para obtener una lista de un objeto de tipo:

> [(Id: 0, Descripcion: "Prueba"; (Id: 1, Descripcion: "Asd")]

Lo que quiero es dado valor (en este caso un integer para representar el Id), obtener cual es la descripción. Leí que con `$.each()` se puede hacer algo pero no estaría entendiendo como funciona.

Probé hacer esto:

```
function ObtenerTipoSitLaboral(id, lista) {
debugger;
$.each(lista, function (){
    if (lista.Id == id) {
        return lista.Descripcion;
    }
});
```

Pero no esta haciéndolo bien. Alguna sugerencia? Gracias.

Comment: Hola. A que te refieres que no lo está haciendo bien? Te da algún error o no te muestra lo que esperas?

Comment: No me da error, como que se salta el ciclo o no entra al if. No se si estoy usando mal la funcion porque es la primera vez que la uso

Comment: Por que la etiqueta c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba a indicar el `index` y el `value` (parámetros) en la función del `$.each`.

```
function ObtenerTipoSitLaboral(id, lista) {
debugger;
$.each(lista, function (index, value){
    if (value.Id == id) {
        return value.Descripcion;
    }
});
```

Comment: Rafael funciono. Estaba leyendo la docu y vi que me estaba faltando eso pero no entendia como funiconaba. Gracias. Otra consulta, cuando hace el return no termina el ciclo, sigue iterando en el each por que no corta? Y aunque el valor de **value.Descripcion** este bien, donde estoy llamando a la funcion y guardando el return me queda como **undefined**

Comment: Disculpa, no entendi. El value.Descripcion esta bien, me esta obteniendo el valor que debería, pero no deja de iterar luego de obtenerlo (sigue subiendo el index) y donde llamo a la funcion en la variable queda como **undefined**
Asi la invoco
**sit = ObtenerTipoSitLaboral(trabajos[i].TipoDeSituacionLaboral, tipoSitLab);**

Comment: @iMSn20: Para salir del bucle del `$.each()` debes hacer un `return false`, pero en tu caso como estás devolviendo la Descripción, deberás deberás pensar otra manera de devolver la Descripción.

Comment: Ok, gracias Rafael. Se me ocurrio hacer una variable global y guardar el valor ahi. Sabrías otra opción para tener en cuenta?

Comment: @iMSn20: Creas una variable para la Descripción `var _desc = null`. Cuando coincida el Id le asignas la descripción a la variable `_desc = value.Descripcion;` y haces el `return false;`. Luego fuera del `$.each()` devuelves la variable `return _desc;`

Comment: Perfecto, pensaba que si retornaba false en el each tambien me lo retornaba como valor de la función. Muchas gracias me gusto mas eso.